# redis-cli "Error: Server closed the connection" when requesting lots of keys

Tags: bash, redis, redis-cli

for some reason running command `KEYS` command on result with millions of keys result in `Error: Server closed the connection`.

```
[nir]$ echo "keys abc" | redis-cli -h $redis
1) "abc"
[nir]$ echo "keys a*"| redis-cli -h $redis
Error: Server closed the connection
```

I guess there is some timeout limit or something, how can I adjust it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to move from `KEYS` to `redis-cli --scan --pattern <pattern>`